# add a first character of text to css

Tags: jquery

I got a challenging task here and really hope that you can help me.

I am taking the info from json feed by ajax and want to add only first character of my **item.title** as **content** css attribute to the **#list > .item:before**

```
 var str = item.title;
 $('#list > .item:before').attr('content', str.substring(0,1));
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. Please advise me a line of code how to make it happen.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: Sushanth how it is possible to do?

Comment: Pseudo elements are not part of the DOM and can not be manipulated  directly using jQuery. You can work aroun it however. This might help you on the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change pseudo-classes with jQuery.

I'd suggest simply prepending it as a `span`:

```
$('#list > .item').prepend('<span>' + str.substring(0,1) + '</span>');
```

And, assuming you have other CSS that's targeting the `:before` to style it, change the CSS selector to `#list > .item > span`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS :first-letter to control the output? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter